# Solve for a variable that is within an integral and the upper bound of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

So I took a Calculas test today and this is a problem that I know I did not get correct. I've been thinking for some time on it and this is as far as I got, any corrections or an answer would be great, thanks

$$28=\int_{2}^{k}(k^2 \sqrt{x})dx$$

$$28=\frac{2}{3}\cdot k^2\cdot \:k^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{3}\cdot \:k^2\cdot 2^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$28=\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot k^{\frac{7}{2}}-\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot k^2$$

$$42=k^{\frac{7}{2}} -2\sqrt{2}\cdot k^2$$

$$k^{\frac{7}{2}} -2\sqrt{2}\cdot k^2-42=0$$

Where do I go from here? I've been asked to produce an exact answer, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting to the point at which you reached the best approach I see is to use newtons method to approximate the root. That is
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
Where $x_0$ equals some initial guess of the root and the larger you make $n$, the more accurate the approximation of the root becomes; assuming it works. In your case
$$f(x)=k^{\frac{7}{2}}-2\sqrt{2}k^2-42$$
and therefore
$$f'(x)=\frac{7}{2}k^{\frac{5}{2}}-4\sqrt{2}k.$$
This is of course only useful if you get a calculator, and in which thats the case you could also just plug it into a graphing system and check the roots. However the root is irrational so I would hope you were allowed a calculator.

Comment: I was allowed to use a calc; however, the question was asking for an exact solution which I don't think is possible to come up with :/